# C# - Load external .exe without mouse wait cursor

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-10, threadpool

From a WinForms app I'm initializing an external (third-party) executable and would like this loading to be hidden.

I'm using a Task.Run () => Process.Start to initialize the process, but even in the background thread (using thread pool) the mouse cursor stays with WaitIcon. I believe it's because of the application loading and Windows is managing this, not my app thread.

```
//I don't even need to await, just start but without the cursor get with WaitIcon

Task.Run(() => System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("ExternalApp.exe"));
```

Is there any simple way to intervene in this process to leave the cursor as Default during external executable loading?

Comment: Always makes it easier if you give us code to work with.

Comment: Hi @LarsTech, did it.

Comment: Isn't Process in the System.Diagnostics namespace?

Comment: Yep. I corrected.